# How to add a class to the classList of an HTMLcollection with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I'm having trouble trying to add a class to an HTMLcollection. What I'm doing is a map is populated on click and it then populates the corresponding county, state, and others in their input/select boxes. I want to take the correct county and state and then add a new class to the county. But I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

Here's my code:

```
            $("#locationStateSelect").val(editedTd5);
            $("#locationCountySelect").append($("<option>", {
                name: "locationCountyName",
                value: editedTd4,
                text: editedTd4
            }));

            countySelect = editedTd4;
            stateSelect = editedTd5;

            stateNameOne = "";
            //get state info
            for (i=0;i<states.length;i++) {
                if(states['StateName'][i] == stateSelect) {
                    stateName = states["StateName"][i];
                    stateIdClass = states['StateId'][i];
                    stateNameOne = stateName.replace(/([A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1');
                }
            }
            countyNameOne = "";
            //get county info and highlight the county
            for(i=0;i<counties.length;i++) {
                if(counties["CountyName"][i] == countySelect && counties['StateId'][i] == stateIdClass) {
                    countyId = counties["CountyId"][i];
                    countyName = counties["CountyName"][i];
                    countyNameOne = countyName.replace(/([A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1');
                }
            }
            var elCounty = document.getElementsByClassName(countyNameOne +" "+ stateNameOne);               
            console.log(elCounty.item(0));

            //fill the correct county
            for(i=0;i<elCounty.length;i++) {
                countyList = elCounty[i];
                console.log(countyList);
                if(countyList.classList.contains(countyNameOne) && countyList.classList.contains(stateNameOne)) {
                    console.log("true");
                    countyList.classList.add("selectedCounty");
                }
            }
```

I keep getting an error saying can't get contains of undefined. I'm using d3 maps if that helps construct this better. All I need to do is add a new class to the HTMLcollection somehow.

Comment: In your `if` statement at the end you're checking against `elCounty` rather than `countyList`

Comment: You're not using `countyList`, you're just defining it. You're trying to access  `elCounty.classList` but `elCounty` is a nodelist. `elCounty.classList` is therefore undefined.

Comment: I've console.logged the elCounty and it is for sure an HTMLcollection.

Comment: After changing the code I still get the same error.

Comment: can you show the html code? Another thing is `document.getElementsByClassName` really returning a collection of div tags I guess?

Comment: is `countyNameOne` or `stateNameOne` being set at the time of the if condition? Can you put some log there to see what the actual value is for both of them?

Comment: I've logged both county and state.. everything is pulling in correctly. I just can't seem to add the new class